# Error in viewing extended DetailView in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm extending a DetailView to show a list of item in the detailed view of an object. Even there are no errors, no output is shown.

Here is the code listing. **In the extended View**

```
class Developer_detail(DetailView):
    model = Developer
    template_name = 'en/public/developer_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(Developer_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            tasks_dev = Task.oblects.filter(developer=self.object)
            context['tasks_dev'] = tasks_dev

            return context
```

**In urls.py**

```
url(r'developer-detail_(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Developer_detail.as_view(), name='developer_detail'),
```

**In the template**

```
{% extends 'en/public/base.html' %}
{% block title_html %}
    Developer Details
{% endblock %}

{% block h1 %}
    Developer Details - {{ object.name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block article_content %}
    <h4>{{ object.name }}</h4>
    <span>Login: {{ object.login }}</span><br />
    <span>Email: {{ object.email }}</span>
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
    <table>
        {% for task in tasks_dev %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.importance }}</td>
            <td>{{ task.project }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p>
        {{ object.description }}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Above template rendering not showing either **object** or **tasks_dev** data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a `get_context_data` inside the `get_context_data` method. It should be:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Only one declaration, otherwise None will be returned by the function
        context = super(Developer_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tasks_dev = Task.oblects.filter(developer=self.object)
        context['tasks_dev'] = tasks_dev

        return context
```